# Error while trying to connect to ibm db2 database through pandas: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_sa

Tags: python, sql, pandas, db2

Hello I'm getting this error while trying to save a Pandas dataframe into the ibm db2 database:

> Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_sa

I tried this solution but is does not work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/jcxq-k9xf.csv')

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://'+ dsn_uid + ':' + dsn_pwd + '@'+dsn_hostname+':'+dsn_port+'/' + dsn_database )

chicago_socioeconomic_dataSQL = df.to_sql('chicago_socioeconomic_data', engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

Anybody can help me?

Thank you,
Matteo

Comment: Did you install the prerequisite plugin ibm_db_sa and ibm_db and a relevant Db2-driver, along with any required licence (if the Db2-server) is running on i-series  or Z/OS) ?

Comment: Yes, solved by installing the ibm_db_sa plugin!
Thank you,
Matteo

Answer (score 3):

Resolved by installing the required pre-requisite module (**ibm_db_sa** ) which will also install the **ibm_db** module and the **ibm_db_dbi** module, and (by default, unless otherwise directed) will also install the `Db2 ODBC and CLI driver` into your site_packages tree.

IF you are connecting to Db2-for-Linux/Unix/Windows, you do not need to install other IBM software or licence files.

If you are connecting directly to Db2-for-i-series (AS/400) , from either Microsoft-Windows, or Linux, then you should first install 'IBM i access' with the optional ODBC/CLI support, and get it configured to connect to your Db2 for i.  Refer to its documentation for details. Set the **IBM_DB_HOME** environment variable to point to the directory where the 'IBM i access' components are installed. It is this environment variable that will tell the `ibm_db` module to not install the regular ODBC/CLI driver and to use your `IBM i access` components instead.  Then you can install the `ibm_db_sa` module which will then use your 'IBM i access' product to communicate with the i-series database.

If you are connecting directly to Db2 for Z/OS, you will be unable to connect without a licence file for Db2-connect, **OR** you can connect indirectly via a separate Db2-connect gateway (in which case you do not then need to deploy a separate licence file). Refer to IBM's instructions for deploying the licence file to the correct location where the clidriver can use it.

Comment: This was helpful!
However, in my case db2 driver needed to be installed seperately.